# Filter or remove item.description from an RSS feed

Tags: regex, rss, twitter, yahoo-pipes

I would like to remove the item.description part of a twitter feed within yahoo pipes and I haven't figured out how to do it yet.

Obviously the filter module will remove posts with that item so I've been trying to use Regex. I think clearing the item.description field would work well enough. Is there a Regex expression that would replace the entire string?

Basically the goal is to make a twitter post that displays only the title and publish date. Basically, the item.description field is producing redundant information.

A copy of the pipe can be found [here](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=d20d9b90da911cffe0db73483c31afc5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would want to use an XSLT to do this - something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//description">
        <description/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But since you are using Pipes, try this regular expression:

> `<description>[^<]*</description>`

with this:

> `<description/>`

as a replacement string.

Comment: This works wonderfully, I plugged [^<]* into the regex module IE - <i>in</i> item.description <i>replace</i> [^<]* <i>with</i> BLANK

Comment: MattyFo, thanks for your example, this worked perfectly.  To reformat your example for readability:  _in_ item.description _replace_ [^<]* _with_ (leave this field blank).

Comment: does this really do what the question asked?  It doesn't remove a field it only nullifies it.

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove the description node, add this right before the output:

[image]